# How to cause a container to take the total width of it's children?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs which are children of a parent div, with each of them having a width in percentage (important: I need the width to be in percentage). But the trick is here, I need to align this entire thing to the center of the page which seems impossible using margin auto trick. Please help!

Here's the code so far:

```
<div class="container" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;">
    <div style="margin: 0px auto;">
        <div class="child1" style="width: 40%; float: left; background: lightblue;">Testing Child 1</div>
        <div class="child2" style="width: 30%; float: left; background: lightgreen">Testing Child 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe instead of using margin: 0px auto, use display:flex; and justify-content: center; ?

Comment: You can use min-width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using floats which will take the elements out of the regular document flow. I defined your `.container` as a flexbox and centered the children via CSS.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child1 {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.child2 {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child1">Testing Child 1</div>
  <div class="child2">Testing Child 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Where can I get a good and thorough guide on the display flex property. I do not like a technical reference, but one which is very easy to understand.

Comment: Works perfectly. Where can I get a good and thorough guide on the display flex property. I do not like a technical reference, but one which is very easy to understand.

Comment: Have a look here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Another issue. This one in the parenthesis: How do I cause the last child to break to another line with responsive design when reached to a specific view port?

Comment: You can define flex-flow: wrap

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox***:

```css
.container {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  justify-content: center; /* centers them horizontally */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child1" style="width: 40%; background: lightblue">Testing Child 1</div>
  <div class="child2" style="width: 30%; background: lightgreen">Testing Child 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use like this -

```
<div class="container" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;text-align: center">
    <div style="margin: 0px auto;">
        <div class="child1" style="width: 40%; float: none; background: lightblue;display: inline-block;">Testing Child 1</div><!--
        --><div class="child2" style="width: 30%; float: none; background: lightgreen;display: inline-block;">Testing Child 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

May it will work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this approach:

```css
#box {
position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;text-align: center">
    <div id="box" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 100%;">
        <div class="child1" style="width: 40%; float: none; background: lightblue;display: inline-block;">Testing Child 1</div><!--
        --><div class="child2" style="width: 30%; float: none; background: lightgreen;display: inline-block;">Testing Child 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add 15% padding on right and left of your container the following way:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 15%;
  background: red;
}
.child1 {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  background: lightblue;
}

.child2 {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child1">Testing Child 1</div>
  <div class="child2">Testing Child 2</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote?? it works, and it had worked before the small edit..